# Cannot downcast logger back to original struct

Tags: rust, traits, downcast

I would like to access my `log::Log` impl instance in order to access a particular field, but once I receive the reference I am not able to downcast it to my struct.

I tried to convert the logger reference into `core::any::Any` and then downcasting it into my original struct, but I always obtain `None`.

```rust
use core::any::Any;

pub trait AToAny: 'static {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl<T: 'static> AToAny for T {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

struct MyLogger {}

impl log::Log for MyLogger {
    fn enabled(&self, _: &log::Metadata<'_>) -> bool { todo!() }
    fn log(&self, _: &log::Record<'_>) { todo!() }
    fn flush(&self) { todo!() }
}

pub fn main() {
    let logger_impl = MyLogger {};
    log::set_boxed_logger(Box::new(logger_impl)).unwrap();
    let logger = log::logger();
    
    let logger_any = logger.as_any();
    let logger_impl = logger_any.downcast_ref::<MyLogger>()
        .expect("downcast failed");
}
```

I also tried without passing from log initialization functions, but I obtain the same result:

```rust
use core::any::Any; // 0.10.1

pub trait AToAny: 'static {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl<T: 'static> AToAny for T {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

struct MyLogger {}

impl log::Log for MyLogger {
    fn enabled(&self, _: &log::Metadata<'_>) -> bool { todo!() }
    fn log(&self, _: &log::Record<'_>) { todo!() }
    fn flush(&self) { todo!() }
}

pub fn main() {
    let logger_impl = MyLogger {};
    let logger_boxed: Box<MyLogger> = Box::new(logger_impl);
    let logger: &'static mut dyn log::Log = Box::leak(logger_boxed);
    
    let logger_any = logger.as_any();
    let logger_impl = logger_any.downcast_ref::<MyLogger>()
        .expect("downcast failed");
}
```

Here is the [code on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use+core%3A%3Aany%3A%3AAny%3B+%2F%2F+0.10.1%0A%0Apub+trait+AToAny%3A+%27static+%7B%0A++++fn+as_any%28%26self%29+-%3E+%26dyn+Any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3A+%27static%3E+AToAny+for+T+%7B%0A++++fn+as_any%28%26self%29+-%3E+%26dyn+Any+%7B%0A++++++++self%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+MyLogger+%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl+log%3A%3ALog+for+MyLogger+%7B%0A++++fn+enabled%28%26self%2C+_%3A+%26log%3A%3AMetadata%3C%27_%3E%29+-%3E+bool+%7B+todo%21%28%29+%7D%0A++++fn+log%28%26self%2C+_%3A+%26log%3A%3ARecord%3C%27_%3E%29+%7B+todo%21%28%29+%7D%0A++++fn+flush%28%26self%29+%7B+todo%21%28%29+%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub+fn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+logger_impl+%3D+MyLogger+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++log%3A%3Aset_boxed_logger%28Box%3A%3Anew%28logger_impl%29%29.unwrap%28%29%3B%0A++++let+logger+%3D+log%3A%3Alogger%28%29%3B%0A++++%0A++++%2F%2F+let+logger_impl+%3D+MyLogger+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++%2F%2F+let+logger_boxed%3A+Box%3CMyLogger%3E+%3D+Box%3A%3Anew%28logger_impl%29%3B%0A++++%2F%2F+let+logger%3A+%26%27static+mut+dyn+log%3A%3ALog+%3D+Box%3A%3Aleak%28logger_boxed%29%3B%0A++++%0A++++let+logger_any+%3D+logger.as_any%28%29%3B%0A++++let+logger_impl+%3D+logger_any.downcast_ref%3A%3A%3CMyLogger%3E%28%29%0A++++++++.expect%28%22downcast+failed%22%29%3B%0A%7D).

I saw that the `type_id` of the `logger` variable is different from the `type_id` of the `logger_impl` so I believe that this is what is preventing me from doing the downcast, but I cannot understant how I am supposed to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `<&dyn Log>::as_any`, but you can only downcast that to `&dyn Log`, that is `logger_any.downcast_ref::<&dyn log::Log>()` returns `Some`, but it gets you nowhere. A `&dyn Log` does not expose the information necesary to downcast to `MyLogger`.

Fortunately you don't need `Any` or downcasting at all here since you can set the gobal logger with only a shared reference and still access the logger itself since shared references implement `Copy`:

```rust
struct MyLogger {
    bar: &'static str,
}
impl MyLogger {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("foo")
    }
}
pub fn main() {
    let logger: &MyLogger = Box::leak(Box::new(MyLogger { bar: "baz"}));
    log::set_logger(logger as &dyn log::Log).unwrap(); // the cast is not needed, but illustrates what's happening implicitly otherwise.
    logger.foo(); // can still call inherent MyLogger::foo
    println!("{}", logger.bar); // and access fields.
}
```